# Laravel check for unique rule without sending the attribute as data rather as url parameter

Tags: php, laravel, validation, eloquent, request

I have a products table and a product_reports table. A user can report a product but he should only be able to do this once and not twice or multiple times.

This is my products table:

```
id, heading, text, price, stock
```

This is my product_reports:

```
id, product_id, user_id, reason
```

My product expired route:

```
Route::post('product/{product}/report', ['as' => 'product.report', 'uses' => 'ProductController@report']);
```

Now I a ProductReportRequest.php file which is located in `App\Http\Requests`. There I check if the user is authorized and also if he has send a reason (value):

```
public function authorize()
{
    return Auth::check();
}

public function rules()
{
    return [
        'value' => [
            'required',
            'string',
            'max:65535'
        ],
    ];
}
```

My question is now the following:

As you can see, the route already contains the product (id) for which I want to store the report by the user. So I am not sending the product id as a attribute in the post request but rather in the url which look like this for example: `product/5/report`.

My goal is now to add a rule which checks if there is already an entry in the product_reports table for the user with the user_id, e.g. `2`, and and for the product with the product_id `5`.
If so, the request should end in a `422` http code which is the typical http code if the request doesn't mach the rules.

But remember, the combination of both, user_id and product_id, has to be unique! Because one user can report many products and on product can by reported by many users!

I have already found the `unique` validation rule in the [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/validation#rule-unique) but I think they just apply to request attributes and not the url. How can I validate that without sending the user_id and product_id as attributes of the request?

PS: I am using Laravel 6.x.

Kind regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need a custom rule, smth like:

```
<?php

namespace App\Rules;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule;

class OneProductPerUser implements Rule
{
    /**
     * @var int
     */
    private $userId;
    /**
     * @var int
     */
    private $productId;

    public function __construct($userId, $productId)
    {
        $this->userId = $userId;
        $this->productId = $this->productId;
    }

    /**
     * Determine if the validation rule passes.
     *
     * @param  string  $attribute
     * @param  mixed  $value
     * @return bool
     */
    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        //import the correct Eloquent model of the ProductReport model
        $reports = ProductReport::where('user_id', $this->userId)->where('product_id', $this->productId)->count();

        return $reports === 0;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation error message.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function message()
    {
        return 'User has already report for this product ID ' . $this->productId;
    }
}
```

then in your `FormRequest` you need to call it like:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'value' => [
            'required',
            'string',
            'max:65535',
            new OneProductPerUser(Auth::user()->id, $this->route('product'))
        ],
    ];
}
```

I haven't checked but you might access the user object with `$this->user()->id`

Answer (score 0):

You can start with creating custom rule:

MyRules.php

```php
class MyRules {
    public static function existsForClient($table, $field) {
        return Rule::exists($table, $field)->where(function($query) {
            $query->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id);
        });
    }
}
```

And use that rule like this:

```php
function rules() {
  return [
    'value' => [
      'required',
      'string',
      'max:65535',
      MyRules::existsForUser('products', 'product_id'),
    ]
  ];

}
```

Of course you need add valid namespace to MyRules class.

Comment: That's not working. I just tried it. The same user can add reports for one product multiple times. Also, how can I check two columns? Simply add a second query?

Comment: @Jan, I've updated my answer changing from unique to exists. Try it.

Comment: Nope.. sadly not working. I still can insert multiple reports...

Comment: Even if I want to check just the `product_id` its not working... I have added `'unique:products_reports,product_id'` but I still can insert multiple reports

Comment: @Jan First of all you have to make that constraint in migration, in other words in database table you have to make constraint index that only one of a kind of same user_id and same product_id can be saved. Then you need to work on PHP validation and at the end on frontend JS/HTML validation if appropriate for your application. Also, rules of validation have nothing with saving data. Meaning if some misconception occurs, DB won't prevent saving. For that you need to set correct indices/constraint. I.e. `$table->index(['user_id', 'product_id']);` [Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/migrations).